# C# need regular expression to capture the second occurence after a underscore

Tags: c#, regular-language

I am using the regular expression below to capture all numbers/letters after a underscore but I need to capture only the second occurence i.e "00500" as you see below:

```
regular expresion: (?<=_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+

string:
"-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats rats 31K Sep 17 13:33 /opt/data/automation_sent/20180918/labc/0/20180918_00500.itx"
```

I am doing in C# and I thought the value would be in the second group[1] but it is not; it only captures the string "_sent":

```
        string temp2 = "";
        Regex getValueAfterUnderscore = new Regex(@"(?<=_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        Match match2 = getValueAfterUnderscore.Match(line);
        if (match2.Success)
        {
            temp2 = match2.Groups[1].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(temp2); 
        }
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression? Is this number that you want to capture always going to be right before the file extension (.itx)?

Comment: If you just want the second match: `getValueAfterUnderscore.Matches(line)[1].Value`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What is special about “the second occurence after a underscore”? It's part of a filename? Then use [filename methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.1), not regular expressions because file names and paths can have any number of underscores anywhere in the string, so looking for the “second” one isn't going to get a filename.

Comment: thanks Nico S. That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following code that capture text after second underscore

```
 var line = "-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats rats 31K Sep 17 13:33 /opt/data/automation_sent/20180918/labc/0/20180918_00500.itx";
            string temp2 = "";
            Regex getValueAfterUnderscore = new Regex(@"_.+_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)");
            Match match2 = getValueAfterUnderscore.Match(line);
            if (match2.Success)
            {
                temp2 = match2.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(temp2); 
            }
```

output:

```
00500
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confusing "groups" with "matches". You should search for matches of your regular expression. Here's how to list all matches of your regex in a given string:

```
string str = "-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats rats 31K Sep 17 13:33 /opt/data/automation_sent/20180918/labc/0/20180918_00500.itx";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=_)[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
foreach (Match curMatch in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(curMatch.Value);
```

For your specific case, verify if there are at least 2 matches and retrieve the value of `matches[1]` (which is the second match).

```
if (matches.Count >= 2)
    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {matches[1].Value}");
```

Comment: As a side note, there are some quite interesting tools you can use when developing with regex. Have a look at [Regexr](https://regexr.com/3vmpj), for instance. It's the one I usually use.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "-rw-rw-rw- 1 rats rats 31K Sep 17 13:33 /opt/data/automation_sent/20180918/labc/0/20180918_00500.itx";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Identifier1>\d+)_(?<Identifier2>\d+)");
    var results = regex.Matches(input);
    foreach (Match match in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Identifier1"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Identifier2"].Value);//second occurence
    }
```

tested here : http://rextester.com/SIMXNS63534

Answer (score 0):

If all your strings look like this pattern *{**SOME_STRING}***_*{YOUR_NUMBER}*.itx, then you can use this solution (without regex)

```
var arr = str.Split(new[] {"_", ".itx"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var result = arr[arr.Length - 1];
```